# Wrap pattern std::begin; return begin(c); into a function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Is there a way to wrap the pattern into a general, template function?

```
template <typename C>
auto Begin(C&& c) -> ??? {
  using std::begin;
  return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
}
```

The question here is how to write the return type of the function here?

The reason I want this is I want to write a template variable

```
template <typename C>
constexpr bool IsBidirectionalContainer = 
  std::is_base_of<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                  typename std::iterator_traits<
                      decltype(std::begin(std::declval<C>()))>::iterator_category>::value;
```

The problem here is the `std::begin` won't find custom overloads of `begin` for `C` via ADL. If anyone has workaround for this, it is welcome as well.

Comment: I forget whether it's C++14 or C++17, but at least with C++17 you don't have to declare the return type in this case. The compiler will figure it out for you. Otherwise, just use `decltype`.

Comment: @NirFriedman, no, not exactly the same. It uses ADL. See "User-defined overloads" in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin

Comment: Yeah, sorry misunderstood. Overloading the free begin function is kind of weird/unidiomatic though; it should be implemented as a member.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, for C++14, how to do that? decltype only takes an expression, so you can't have both `using std::begin;` and `begin(c)`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In 14 you can leave off the trailling decltype, but auto will deduce to the value type afaik, so it will be wrong for a function returning a reference.

Comment: The real reason why you'd want to specify the trailing return type post C++14 is for SFINAE friendliness. If you needed to be able to deduce a reference, you'd just use `decltype(auto)`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to be able to pick up a free `begin` function declared not inside of a namespace. That's kind of tricky. The standard way of customizing the behavior of `begin` is via ADL; free functions at the same namespace as the type you are defining

Comment: @Justin, if I understand you correctly, If I just write it as `decltype(auto) Begin(C&& c) { using std::begin; return begin(std::forward<C>(c)); }`. it will break SFINAE?

Comment: The code you've posted compiles correctly for me with `-> ???` omitted ... perhaps you could post a MCVE showing more clearly where you are running into trouble?

Comment: @KanLi Using `decltype(auto)` as you show there is not SFINAE friendly. The trailing return type is necessary for SFINAE friendliness, as the `-> decltype(...)` is a "SFINAE context", whereas the body of the function is not.

Comment: I don't think it's needed. If you type `begin` without `std::`, then ADL will take care of selecting the right overload.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Except in those cases where your container isn't in `std::`, and then ADL won't. Or your container is a raw array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap it inside another namespace, i.e:

```
namespace details {
    using std::begin;

    template <typename C>
    auto Begin(C&& c) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<C>(c)))
    {
        return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
    }
}
```

Then:

```
template <typename C>
constexpr bool IsBidirectionalContainer = 
  std::is_base_of<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
                  typename std::iterator_traits<
                      decltype(details::Begin(std::declval<C>()))>::iterator_category>::value;
```

If for some reason you refuse to define `Begin` inside a namespace, you can just use a type alias to get around it.

```
namespace details {
     using std::begin;

     template <typename C>
     using type = decltype(begin(std::forward<C>(c)));
}

template <typename C>
auto Begin(C&& c) -> details::type<C>
{
     return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
}
```

Although that's probably more work than necessary. A forward declaration is probably sufficient.

Comment: I use this; I call `Begin` `adl_begin` to make its purpose clear.

Comment: Last implementation of `Begin` is missing a `using std::begin`. Easier to take your first impl and stick a `using details::Begin` in the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re going to wrap it, I think “why not use the latest best ideas?”  Specifically, Eric Niebler [makes an argument](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) that these should be function-call objects, not functions!

Here is my fresh version using a C++17 compiler

```
// ===================
// would be in a reusable header

namespace twostep {

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    inline auto Begin = [](auto&& r) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r))) {
        return begin(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r));
    };

    inline auto End = [](auto&& r) -> decltype(end(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r))) {
        return end(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r));
    };

}

using twostep::Begin;
using twostep::End;
```

Now since this is not replacing the implementation of the `std::begin`/`end` functions, I don’t get all the benefit that Eric points out.  But, in addition to acting as a wrapper that does the two-step for me, as a normal template function implementation can do, it is itself immune from ADL.

If I refer to `twostep::Begin` with qualification, it doesn’t matter.  But if I import those into my own scope as this listing does to global scope, than an unqualified call to `Begin(r)` will for-sure see the *one* that I have made visible at this point, and not find functions named `Begin` in different namespaces because of all the types involved in `r`.